# Angular, data not loaded using HttpClient

Tags: angular

I am trying to retrieve data from JSON and show it on my angular App. but its got nothing, I don't know why.

here's my JSON URL like `example.com/api/v1/show/1`

```
{
    "login_in": 1,
    "status": "ok"
}
```

here my `config.service.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';

export interface Config {
  status: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  configUrl = 'example.com/api/v1/show/1';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getConfig() {
    return this.http.get(this.configUrl);
  }
}
```

here my `app.components.ts`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Config, ConfigService } from './config/config.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [ ConfigService ],
})

export class AppComponent {
  config: Config;

  constructor(private configService: ConfigService) {}

  showConfig() {
    this.configService.getConfig()
      .subscribe((data: Config) => this.config = {
          status: data['status'],
      });
  }
}
```

and here my `app.components.html`

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Welcome to {{ title }}!
  </h1>

  <p>Textfile URL is "{{config.status}}"</p>
```

on my cmd

```
 ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

but result

```
Textfile URL is "
```

not showing my `status`, what I missed?...

Comment: ` <p>Textfile URL is "{{config.status}}"</p>`

Comment: @Milad still not showing

Comment: Well, you're going to need to give us some more information -- are you getting an error? Is the network request being made? Is your subscriber method being called?

Comment: ` <p>Textfile URL is "{{config | json}}"</p>`  see what's inside it

Comment: `Textfile URL is ""` on my browser

Comment: also, see what's coming back : .subscribe((data: Config) => console.log('data',data));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere where you are calling the showConfig() method.

Try this:

```
   ngOnInit() {
    this.showConfig();
   }

    showConfig() {
        this.configService.getConfig()
          .subscribe((data: Config) => {
              this.config = data;
          });
     }
```

Comment: this is working. theres no `ngOnInit()` on this documentation `https://angular.io/guide/http` so i confused.

Comment: @DickyRaambo ngOnInit() is part of the lifecycle hooks from angular. After the component has been loaded, you can trigger functions inside of the ngOnInit(). https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks and https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit

Comment: if this answer worked, don't forget to mark it as the correct answer not just upvoting :)

Comment: okay, thank you! need to read more the documentation, i missed so much parts. please upvote my question also, ppl don't like a noob asking always downvote, that makes noob like me hard to get learned. lol

Comment: Take the angular hero tutorial. It's short and had the good basics to get you rolling